# DB2 group by and return id with max date

Tags: group-by, db2, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

I'm having a little headache to make a query, maybe someone can help with it.

> My table fields (ID, FIELD1, FIELD2, STATUS, DATE).

Lets assume that I want to group by FIELD1 and FIELD2 and order by max(DATE). In my response I need to show the ID and STATUS field.

Is this possible?

In advance, thanks!

Comment: It is of course possible, to answer your question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried the following sql, but in general the example is simple, my table is very large and complex, so I'm afraid that could be hazardous to the database: WITH select_1 as (select FIELD1, FIELD2, max(DATE) max_date from fields group by FIELD1, FIELD2 order by max_date) select ID, STATUS from fields where (FIELD1, FIELD2, DATE) in (select FIELD1, FIELD2, max_date from select_1)

Comment: Ok, so you know it's possible and you have written a query to do what you need. What's your next question?

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, I was trying to see if someone could give me a better solution. Mine doesn't seems to be performative.

Comment: Then you should rephrase your question, stating what query you are running, showing its execution plan, and indicating what you mean by "not performative" and how performative you expect it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you seem to want is just the "newest" version of each field1/field2 combination. There are a couple of ways to do this, but doing a correlated sub-select would probably be the easiest (not necessarily the fastest, but pretty performant):

```
SELECT
     FIELD1
    ,FIELD2
FROM fields A
WHERE date = (
    SELECT MAX(date)
    FROM fields B
    WHERE A.field1 = b.field1
      AND A.field2 = b.field2
)
```

Obviously, an index on `field1, field2, date` would make this run a little faster.

My guess is that one of your performance issues is that the database has to create an internal work file in order to do the `ORDER BY` in your `WITH` clause... which isn't actually needed. You're already getting the "max" date for each combination, and then ordering those "max" combinations by the `max_date`. Then, you're doing an `IN`, and order of the rows doesn't matter there.

Comment: Yes, thats correct bhamby. The newest is the goal. Like I said in other reply is that example is very simple. My actual table has more than 8 million rows (and growing fast) and the group by is made by 13 columns. Moreover I've made a view to arrange my business situation and with that I'm doing this. Thanks for your answer I'll try to explicit this predicate to avoid WITH.

Comment: It's not that `WITH` is inherently bad, it's that the `ORDER BY` (especially if you're returning a lot of rows) will take a while, because it has to do the internal work to sort... and then, it's not even used.

Comment: Got it. I tried to remove, the planner doesn't seems to care about the order by.